# All-round budget lens upgrade

Tags: lens, canon

I'm looking for a decent all-purpose lens to replace the 18-55mm kit lens on my Canon EOS Rebel XTi (400D). I'd like to keep the price as low as possible but something with a half-decent zoom and IS.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The kit lens _is_ a decent, all-purpose lens. What's wrong with it? A few specific examples would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe more useful would be a lens that _isn't_ an "all-purpose" lens?

Comment: @osulic Not the one that came with  the 400D. I remember previews of the 450D praising the new kit lens on it (first one with IS I think...).

Comment: What is "half-decent zoom"? Your perception of what might constitute "decent" is likely different from someone else's — let alone "half-decent".

Comment: I stirred too much sh... recently to ask the underlying "what happened to the $300 sigma answer to every lens" question :)

Comment: @osullic The EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 II (non-IS) was known as a particularly poor kit lens. Canon's QC seemed to be all over the place with that lens. The one I had was [*horrible*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/38630/15871). The EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS that replaced it performed much better. The difference seemed to be mostly about quality control rather than design, but everyone reviewing kit lenses and cameras noticed the improvement.

Comment: It's probably above the price range you want, but long ago I was very happy with the all round performance of Tamron's 18-250mm. This was later updated to 18-275 and then 18-300 (I think). While no 'superzoom' has the performance of a comparable price zoom of lower range, I'd expect the Tamron to outperform your existing lens.

Answer (score 0):

Given the kit lens of the 400D, you can either:

- get a modern version of the 18-55. But it's a bit of a minefield, because Canon reintroduced a non-OS version for the low-end cameras. So make sure you have IS, IS II or IS STM (on a 400D, the STM isn't very useful as a "video" lens but you may enjoy the non-rotating front lens). Since these are kit lenses, many are available on the second-hand market if you want rock-bottom prices.
- get something a bit more expensive but slightly faster and with more reach, like the Sigma 17-70 f/2.8-4 (either the IS, or the IS contemporary)
- or something faster with less reach: a 17-50 f/2.8 from various brands (Sigma, Tamron)